# Why the runtimepath in vim cannot be set as a variable

Tags: vim

I've specified the `.vimrc` and `.vim` location.

In my [vimrc file](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L36), I found the `runtimepath` can be set as a **absolute value** likes:

```
set rtp+=~/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle
```

But it **CANNOT** be set as a **variable**, likes:

```
let vudpath = expand(~/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle)
set rtp+=vudpath
```

Why's that? Is there any way can make `runtimepath` be set as variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As romainl said, you have `:let &option`. But in your case, as you want to add a path to a list of paths it would be:

```
exe 'set rtp+=' . expand('~/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle')
```

That will only add the path if it isn't present in &rtp yet.

Or (note the use of the `.=` operator instead of the `+=` one)

```
let &rtp .= ','.expand('~/.marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle')
```

However this time if it is already present in your &rtp, it will be added again. As such, prefer using `:execute`+`:set` in your specific case.

Comment: You are awsome!!! Two ways are all work for me!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's not being said here, is that your problem had nothing to do with "let". Most ex commands do NOT expand variable names, i.e. they do not take an expression. "set" is not one of the commands that expands expressions (variables).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

```
execute "set option=" . expression
let &option = expression
```

Comment: If the `let &option = expression`, why [call vundle#begin(bud)](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc_PublicEnv#L37) works fine?

Comment: Okay, you means, if the option using `+=` method, then the value CANNOT be variable?